# Compare Xamarin.Android CPL localization techniques (.xml .po .mo .resx .xlf)

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, localization

I have inherited an Xamarin Crossplatform project, (Android only,) that had a '**strings.xml**' file with some button-names in it.
Need to find a way to add **more** languages easily and convert **code-strings** to translatable **too** (>300+), not just component-Texts.

I've tried **many** things so far, but nothing worked as expected: [*]
*( Most of the examples and help are for Xamarin.Forms only. )*

1.) installed **ResX** manager

- it did not recognized my XML files
- created .resx files manually, but those have nothing to do with existing xml-translations
- could not get back those texts from C# code I've inserted at the manager window

2.) created a second strings.xml >> placed into values-hu folder >> copied XML content >> translated inside the XML.

- It works only for buttons in the IDE placed into the activity
- can NOT get text with GetText(...,...) from my C# code because it needs an (int)...I don't know how to generate and pair with my own constants
- Resources.Strings... does not pop up any of my own string either
- whenever I try to add a new element at the IDE, 
  I have to search and copy manually the new lines to each XML one by one
- there is no "translator window" for them like ResX
- can not group strings inside the XML file

3.) installed **Multilingual App Toolkit 4.0**

- seems to be just a different file format than .resx, but same problems
- complained about not connected to Azure
- offered me a "new english" translation from my original english XML
- could not add NEW lines, etc.

4.) installed POEdit + **Nuget>GetText**

- at first sight this seemed to be the perfect solution, but
- PoEdit has found only 4 strings in my .cs files
  ( preferences' I/O strings with GetText() method to read from my config.xml )
- could not import string.xml files to translate for 3. lang.
- do not understand the .po > .mo conversion concept
- installed the nuGet GetText > but no new sub-menu appeared anywhere inside VS.

5.) upgraded to VS2017
6.) asked on a local forum, but nobody answered.
7.) Searched through ca 100 topics here >> ... most of them are about Xamarin **Forms** ... but those seems to be invalid for droid.

[*] by **expected** I've imagined having a simple wizard where I can:

- go through each string in my *.cs files, where I can give a constant name and it's converting "Really Exit" > to: _tr(Res.Main.really_exit)
- or mark to skip
- should have a manager to easy translate (like ResX), or ADD new lines!
- having both component-texts and code-string inside ONE(/ language?) file
- possibly group strings by activity / logic. (So translators can see where is what)
  ... but nothing seems to be able to **handle strings.xml files and .cs file-string all in one easily.**

> > So... Now I am totally confused. I've spent a whole week to see some kind of "order" in this chaos, but could not find a proper writing that explains, *WHAT METHOD* should someone use to do things **easily** for droid translation and why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your second approach because it uses the Android build-in localization system. A benefit of using it is that it already has a fallback-solution included, if a language or a key for one language could not be found.

You can use it in your layout files:

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/LogOn_Login"
```

or inside code:

```
var progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.Indeterminate = true;
progressDialog.SetCancelable(false);

progressDialog.SetMessage(GetString(Resource.String.LogOn_ProgressMessage));
```

But you need to know the difference between an Activity and a Fragment.
In an Activity you just need to call GetString(). Which requires an int, that you get from `Resource.String.YOUR_KEY`. But in a Fragment you have to give the context. The call changes to Activity.GetString().

New languages or strings can easily added. I usually add new string to the strings.xml inside values-folder first. That way I make sure I have the fallback ready. A new string has the following semantics:

```
<string name="KEY">VALUE</string>
```

Filled with real data:

```
<string name="LogOn_ProgressMessage">Authenticating...</string>
```

After saving the strings.xml file, it turns out to be good to rebuild the project to make sure the `Resource.designer.cs` is updated. I sometimes saw the behavior that otherwise my newly added keys where not accessible with `Resource.Strings`.

When it comes to editing the strings.xml, I am with you that there is no "translator window" and that you have to copy each new key to all supported languages. To overcome this issue we build us a tool that creates all those files for use on every build. This way we support a quite large app with more than 21 languages.

Comment: I've just faced all those problems with these methods you wrote very detailed about. 1.) I don't always have an active Activity, because sometimes this app is running as a background service only. So could not solve the Fragment problem. 2.) Could not find any windows-tool to translate those XML files easily, had to copy lines one by one. 3.) Very annoying and time consuming to always rebuild and rebuild and rebuild the project after a few translated lines. Without that the C# code is always full of red error lines. Is that tool available for download you wrote? I was going to write one myself

Comment: This tool is not public available yet.

Answer (score -1):

With Xamarin I would go down the .Resx files route. string.xml files are an Android solution and don't fit very well into the .NET world.

How to localize your code is nicely explained here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/

And with Reshaper you can extract all the strings from your code: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html

Yes, you will have to convert your XML files. In what format are they? You might be able to use this tool:
http://converter.webtranslateit.com/

To use .NET Resource files inside your Library, you have to add the resources to your project first and configure them like below:

[image]

Now you can use them for example like this:

```
BillManagement.ResourceManager.GetString("TaxSetupWrong")
```

Or

```
LibraryName.Resources.BillManagement.TaxSetupWrong
```

Comment: **1.]** Your link to official localization is for Xamarin.Forms, so it is not working for CPL projects, like mine. I will edit the main question so it gets more obvious.  **2.]** Resharper looks great, but it is not free.  **3.]** WTI Converter looks really great, thans for the link!  **4.]** By _'getting the texts'_ I mean how to write a C# code that searches and gives back translated constants in runtime. Like: _tr(Res.Main.really_exit) or similar.

Comment: There is a free 30-day trial of Resharper. That should give you enough time to extract all strings from your code. In the future I would recommend you directly use resource files anyway, so you don't need that feature anymore. 
I'll update my answer to show how to use resources inside your CPL code.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help so far! Are you saying this is the **only** way to make everything easier? If I convert the current XML files too, how will they work at buttons? Also... is there no "shortcut" to these long names _BillManagement.ResourceManager.GetString("TaxSetupWrong")_ ? So in your experience .resx type localization is the best ... compared to other methods? (I've red somewhere they cannot be used in debug mode.) Or others can not be used for native CPL projects at all?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. There are all typ of approaches. But .resx files are the official .NET solution. And since Xamarin is running on .NET I would recommend that.